# Tabulator: How to set css on Tabulator editable cell?

Tags: tabulator

I want set css on Tabulator cell with using "list" editor,formatter,and editable condition.

```
 {title:"Title",field:"FieldName", editor:"list", editorParams:{values:{0:"none", 1:"param1", 2:"param2"}}, formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:{0:"none", 1:"param1", 2:"param2"}, width:120, editable:editCheck},
```

- editCheck returns true or false according to other cell values.

I could only find a solution using formatter. But it conflict with "lookup".
And I tried to use tableBuilt event but not good solution on performance and it doesn't work well.

```
table.on("tableBuilt", function(){
            var rows = table.getRows();
            rows.forEach(function(row){
                var cells = row.getCells();
                cells.forEach(function(cell){
                    if(typeof cell.edit !== undefined){
                        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#1e3b20";
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    table.on("tableBuilt", function(){
        var rows = table.getRows();
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            var cells = row.getCells();
            cells.forEach(function(cell){
                if(cell.getColumn().getDefinition().editor != undefined){
                    cell.getElement().classList.add("editable-cell");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And add this CSS

```
.editable-cell:hover {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works only upper records...
When scroll to see lower record, they don't have class.

Comment: I also set css for scrollVertical, it works well.
Thank you.